# Searching a file with grep

Tags: regex, linux, search, grep

Trying to search a dictionary with grep for words with 7 or less letters only containing "i" and "e" and display the number of match's for a project.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction. I can find only 7 letter words or words containing i,e but cant seem to work out how to get it to do both at the same time.

cheers :)

Comment: I don't think there are any words that only contain `i` and `e`. Do you mean these are the only vowels?

Comment: Please provide few examples of words that should match.

Comment: Need to search for words containing ether 'i' or 'e' or both that are between 1-7 letters long. So 'champion' 'messenger' would not show (over 7 letters) but something such as 'leak' 'simple' would as contain 7 or less letters.

Comment: Pipe the two greps together.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so we can see where you are stuck.

Comment: Don't you love it when a question is closed just as you're hitting submit on an answer...

Comment: If using a version of GNU grep that supports PCRE: `grep -P '^(?=.*[ei]).{1,7}$' /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l`

Comment: @Shawn Even though I knew there was a solution using lookahead, I still preferred to post my pipe solution as I think it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the two greps:

```
grep -E '^.{1,7}$' filename | grep '[ie]'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :D thank you so much! Now i can get some sanity back and rest.